# Show all post type posts in manage users posts column

Tags: custom-post-types, users

In my system I have several users, and each have products and posts under them.

In Manage Users page, each user's posts column only counts the posts post-type.

How can I add additional post types to this value?

Will I need an additional column for each post type, in case i want that value to be clickeable, and lead to a list of thee available posts [of specific post type]?

Comment: so instead of `5`  you want `2 posts, 3 pages`?

Comment: @TomJNowell I want it to include custom post types.